# Azure powershell command to get the uptime for all vms

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to generate a report where can I see uptime for all my VMs using PowerShell.

We are using AzureRmVM-(Resource manager) for those VMs.

At the moment I have found something like this:

```
ForEach ($vm in $vmsList) { $vm.Name + " - " + $vm.ResourceGroupName }

get-vm | where {$_.state -eq 'running'} | sort Uptime | select Name,Uptime,@{N="MemoryMB";E={$_.MemoryAssigned/1MB}},Status
```

How can I do that using powershell - rm(Resource manager)?

Comment: I don't see anything relevant in the AzureRM.Compute module

Comment: @4c74356b41 hmm, but is there a way how to do this or it's like impossible ? :D maybe something like this, check start up time and then substract from todays_date.

Comment: well, just look at the resource itself, I don't think Azure tracks that in anyway

Answer (score 3):

**Collect all running VMs of your Subscription:**

```
$AllVMs = Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object { $_.PowerState -Like 'VM running' }
```

Then interate through each VM, catch the Audit Log, search for the VM start and calculate the Time difference to the current Time.

```
# Create Custom Object
$UptimeReport = @()

# Walk through each VM
foreach ($VM in $AllVMs) {

    # Get Subscription Information
    $ctx = Get-AzContext
    Write-Host "Check: '$($VM.Name)' in Subscription '$($ctx.Subscription.Name)'"
    
    # Get the Activity Log of the VM
    $VMAzLog = Get-AzLog -ResourceId $VM.Id `
    | Where-Object { $_.OperationName.LocalizedValue -Like 'Start Virtual Machine' } `
    | Sort-Object EventTimestamp -Descending `
    | Select-Object -First 1
    $BootTime = $VMAzLog.EventTimestamp

    if ($BootTime) {
        $Uptime = '{0}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}' -f (24 * $TimeSpan.Days + $TimeSpan.Hours), $TimeSpan.Minutes, $TimeSpan.Seconds
    }
    else {
        $Uptime = "n/a" 
    }

    if ($BootTime) {
        
        $TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Start $($VMAzLog.EventTimestamp) -End (Get-Date)

        $UptimeReport += [PSCustomObject]@{
            VM             = $VM.Name
            SubscriptionId = $ctx.Subscription.id
            Uptime         = $Uptime
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, print the Result:

```
# Print Result
return $UptimeReport | Sort-Object -Property VM | ft * -AutoSize
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: But this will only give the uptime from the time the server was last rebooted/ from the time server is running continuously , right? Is there a way to get the monthly uptime data (the total time the server was running in a month, irrespective of the no. of starts and stops of the servers) of the server using powershell script?

Comment: This is possible with LogAnalytics Account and Monitoring Agent. You can count the Heartbeat. Or you are using the Cost-API

Comment: @Gill-Bates, I got this when executing the script: WARNING: There are more than 100 VMs in the result.  Only the statuses of 100 VMs are shown to avoid throttling.  To get the actual status of each VM, please provide a VM name with -Status parameter.

Comment: Omit the ``-Status`` Flag! Like this: ``$AllVMs = Get-AzVM | Where-Object { $_.PowerState -Like 'VM running' }``